# failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

```
>     Warning: include_once(/PoliticalForum/headerSite.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
> directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\mainHome.php on line 16
> 
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening
> '/PoliticalForum/headerSite.php' for inclusion
> (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\mainHome.php on line 16
```

Why do I get that Error when I use include_once:

```
   include_once("/PoliticalForum/headerSite.php");
```

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's because you have included a leading `/` in your file path.  The `/` makes it start at the top of your filesystem.  Note: *filesystem* path, not Web site path (you're not accessing it over HTTP). You can use a *relative* path with `include_once` (one that doesn't start with a leading `/`).

You can change it to this:

```
include_once 'headerSite.php';
```

That will look first in the same directory as the file that's including it (i.e. `C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\` in your example.

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: what should be the path if i use LAMP in ubuntu ?

Comment: if you use composer , don't forget composer dump-autoload specially if you rename any class

Answer (score 9):

include() needs a full file path, relative to the file system's root directory.

This should work:

```
 include_once("C:/xampp/htdocs/PoliticalForum/headerSite.php");
```

Comment: ...or he could just do `include_once("headerSite.php");` which would make the code more portable...

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
define("PATH_ROOT", dirname(__FILE__));
include_once PATH_ROOT . "/PoliticalForum/headerSite.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

Failed to open stream error occurs because the given path is wrong such as:

```
$uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/'.$model->user_photo);
```

It will give an error if the images folder will not allow you to store images,
be sure your folder is readable

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507