# Keep PHP and HTML separated

Tags: php, html

My website prints the user location by calling an API. Say I have the following code all in one file `index.php` on my website:

```
<?php
    $sIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $sURL = "http://ipinfo.io/" .$sIP . "/json";
    $sJSON = file_get_contents($sURL);
    $view = (object) array();
    $view->JSON = $sJSON;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        // global string of Data
        var gsData = <?= $view->JSON ?>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var sRegion = gsData.region;
            $('#result').html(sRegion);
        });
    </script>
    <div>Region from data is:</div>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Though, I need to keep the PHP script and the markup separated. I can't embed the PHP script in a `script` element. What can I do to have a PHP and a HTML file?

Comment: you can use template engines, there are a lot of them

Comment: @Lashane What's a template engine? Sorry for my ignorance if it's something simple.

Comment: In general it is correct and important to keep logic and markup separated. However I see little sense in your given example, since there is no logic involved here. This is "just" a passive view. The fact that some small php snippets are used does not change that.

Comment: @JonathanLam https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT**: Use [`include_once()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7794811/2397327) instead of `include` because you can use relative paths.

You can move the PHP into other files and then `include_once` it back into the main file.

The HTML file will still have to be a `.php` file, but you can include all of your PHP script (besides the `include`) in a different file for better maintainability / readability.

For example:

**script.php**

```
<?php
    $sIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $sURL = "http://ipinfo.io/" .$sIP . "/json";
    $sJSON = file_get_contents($sURL);
    $view = (object) array();
    $view->JSON = $sJSON;
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include_once("script.php") ?>
<!-- ^ is the only PHP you will need to include a separate PHP file -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        // global string of Data
        var gsData = <?= $view->JSON ?>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var sRegion = gsData.region;
            $('#result').html(sRegion);
        });
    </script>
    <div>Region from data is:</div>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I made sure the extensions and the file names were the same but I'm getting this error on localhost: `Warning: include(script.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in - on line 1 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'script.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in - on line 1`. What would you do if you were me? It looks like PHP is unable to find the script.php file.

Comment: Perhaps single-quotes are needed to import a PHP file, not double quotes.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I'm getting the same issue; does it work on your end?

Comment: @CeCeXX Yes, it does work for me... Maybe it's file permissions?

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to get my local printed out, but I guess that's another issue.

Comment: @JonathanLam what about when need to show unknown number of same components (e.g. `.image-container>(.image+.title+.description+.a>button)`) that read multiple rows of a database table for content? How do you get rid of that `<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result)) { ?> <html_component /> <?php } ?>`?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **php framework** like **Laravel, CodeIgniter or CakePHP**, so that you can separate your php logic from html code and then send data to **html** page. It is very good practice for your future career.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the PHP script in a separated PHP file, and use AJAX to call  it, then you use the Javascript to print the JSON data that generated by the PHP script.